# How to generate a column based on multiple conditions in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-science

**I want python code for the given problem.**
***Here is the dataset in CSV format look like:***

```
ID   SCORE
 1     3
 1     5
 1     8
 1     1
 2     6
 2     0
 2     3
 1     6
 1     4
```

From this dataset, I want to create a column named "**OUTPUT**". Condition is when **ID=1**, **SCORE**'s each row should be added until **ID=2** and the sum should be inserted in the **OUTPUT** column. And when **ID=2** similar logic will be applied. Here is the output I want:

```
ID   SCORE  OUTPUT
 1     3      17 
 1     5      17 
 1     8      17 
 1     1      17 
 2     6      9 
 2     0      9 
 2     3      9 
 1     6      10
 1     4      10
```

Comment: this is a nice question but next time post some code that shows your own effort, take some time to read [mcve] and [ask] and you'll get help relatively quickly in the pandas tag :) welcome to SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a custom grouping then use `.transform` and `sum`

```
df['OUTPUT'] = df.groupby(df['ID'].ne(df['ID'].shift())\
                 .cumsum())['SCORE'].transform('sum')


print(df)

   ID  SCORE  OUTPUT
0   1      3      17
1   1      5      17
2   1      8      17
3   1      1      17
4   2      6       9
5   2      0       9
6   2      3       9
7   1      6      10
8   1      4      10
```